# Read and delete a text file in php

Tags: php, text, delete-file

I am making a simple php script which just read a text file from server and delete it after showing on web.Script works well but it reads another file and delete another. It should delete the same file it reads. Any help please. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$mystr = '';
    if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                $info = pathinfo($entry);
                if ($info["extension"] == "txt") { 

$mystr = $entry;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
   }
   if (empty($mystr)) {
    }else{
    $contents = file_get_contents($mystr);
echo $contents;
unlink($mystr);
}


?>
```

**Update**

I dont know the file name, So in a loop I get the file name. I want to read any .txt file in the folder. This I read file one by one and at the same time delete it.

Comment: unlink($mystr); I think this is the line as I read in php.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is just this :

```
foreach(glob('/path/to/dir/*.txt') as $file)
{
    readfile($file);
    unlink($file);
}
```

See [`readfile()`](https://www.php.net/readfile) and [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/glob) manual pages.

Comment: So `glob()` will find it for you

Comment: Thanks for glob() function. But I can get the file name in $mystr. Problem is after reading the file contents script is deleting another file instead of the file which was read by script.

Comment: @user934820 code above works fine for me. It doing `readfile` & `unlink` - both for same `$file`.